# How to modify the "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" variable that appears in the phpinfo() file under Apache Environment?

Tags: apache, caching, ubuntu, cache-control, php

How to modify the "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" variable that appears in the phpinfo() file under Apache Environment?

I have root access on UBUNTU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All environment variables in the form `HTTP_XXX` are the HTTP headers received from the client. The Header name is uppercase, the `-`s replaced by `_`s, and `HTTP_` prefixed.

So `HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL` is the value of the Cache-Control header received from the client. It's not something configured on your server, it's based on what the client sends.